# how to scroll the page in AngularJS application using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to scroll the page on AngularJS application using protractor

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,200);').then(function () {
```

The above code is not getting executed.

Comment: Please clarify your question better. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on Stack Overflow, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to scroll to? The way I handle this is like so:

```
var lastElement = element.all(by.css('td')).last();
browser.actions().mouseMove(lastElement).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sg-protractor-tools

You can use the library's functions by referencing the sgpt object, e.g. for scrolling:

```
sgpt.scroll.scrollTo(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  var scrolldown = by.css(' keep your class here');
    browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
        browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)', scrolldown.getWebElement());
    });
```

Comment: I tried the above code and got message" Failed: scrolldown.getWebElement" is not a function, Please advice as I am new to protractor.